# When use findViewById Ambiguous method call

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My **Activity** extends **Activity_1**, Activity_1 is extends **AppCompatActivity.**

It's been used well, but there's a problem with the SDK version upgrading. The previous version was 23 and has now been raised to 26.

The error, Ambiguous method call, is occurring when using 'findViewById'.

This is my build.gradle.

```
android {

   compileSdkVersion 26

   buildToolsVersion 26.0.2


default {

   targetSdkVersion 26

}

}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
}
```

This is Activity_1

```
public abstract class Activity_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

public <T extends View> T findViewById(int id) {

   return this.a.getPublisherRootView().findViewById(id);

}
```

This is findViewById in AppCompatActivity.

```
@Overrid

public View findViewById(@IdRes int id) {

   return getDelegate().findViewById(id);

}
```

Why does this error occur?

I have already done 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' & 'Sync project with Gradle file'. But these methods are not working.

- I'm using Android studio in offline mode for security.

this is whole app.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "5g"
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

**2018. 09. 10 project build.gradle Added**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your full app.gradle file

Comment: Can you show the Project build.gradle file

Comment: Sorry I'm late. It's editted.